# MATLAB: Quickest way to convert numeric array to a cell array of strings

Tags: string, matlab, numbers, cell

In general terms I need to process many text files with mixed data types, both numeric and text. For the numeric data, I need to process them for quality since I deal with many sources of data and there is no standard I can strictly enforce. The data could be in integer, floating point, or some complex format, and I need to clean these files.

The input data is quickly converted to numbers with textscan, however, trying to convert the newly created numbers back to strings seems to be taking too long (6 times longer than converting the input text to numbers).

I'm currently using a combination of sprintf and textscan to convert a numeric array of doubles into a cell array of strings without losing precision.

```
numstr = sprintf(sprntffrmtstr, num);

vlnmcllnst = textscan(numstr,txtscnfrmtstr,'delimiter',' ');

vlcll = vlnmcllnst{1};
```

Lines 1 and 2 are taking up a significant amount of time in the profiler. I use this scheme in a for loop to process output from the textscan that converted the input text to numbers. Each loop is a column vector of numbers and both numstr and vlnmcllnst were pre-allocated before the loop.

**Can someone speed this up?**

EDIT:
File uploaded here (still reachable in 2014-04-29!): http://www.2shared.com/file/ztVrvE0K/exampledata.html

This is just illustrative of 1 file. I might work with and analyze a couple thousand of these files at a time and they typically vary between 0-7MB (4000 rows) in size, although there is no strict upper size limit. The data channels are only loosely organized by columns, channels may be missing in some files, new channels added, etc. I certainly forsee the need to stay flexible in working with any standard that the files may change to since they come from different sources. I don't need a solution that only works with this one file. My final solution should be capable of working with almost any "legal" .csv type file. I' m not ruling out the possibility of using a helper type function written in perl, C, etc. that can be called from MATLAB, if no native MATLAB code can provide sufficient speed.